# spyder is showing error after update [you have missing dependencies]

Tags: spyder

spyder ide is showing error after new 4.0.0b1 update. Please help.

[image: Refer this image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To fix this error, please open an Anaconda Prompt and run there

`conda update jedi parso`

Comment: Thank you, efficient answer and easy to find.

Answer (score 3):

For me

```
conda update jedi parso
```

didn't fix the issue but I managed to resolve it by running with Admin rights the following commands sequentially in the Anaconda Prompt:

```
pip uninstall jedi
pip uninstall parso
pip install parso==0.5.2
pip install jedi==0.15.2
```

Comment: exactly what I need. This problem may be caused by the conflict of the package' versions.

Answer (score 0):

While installing spyder, spyder need some dependencies to work and if they are missing then it will not work accordingly and in your case during installation few dependencies must have been missed.

Open command prompt
activate the environment you are working in if any and then run the following command it will you update the packages and will work fine

**conda update jedi parso**